# route for Wan To Lan

Tags: network-share, route, netgear

I working on Netgear Prosafe FVS336GV2
My wan interface is on 192.168.1.0
My Lan interface is on 192.168.100.0

Of course my lan access to my wan
But I want to add a route to access to my lan from my wan.

do I doing right or not?
And if yes could you give me the route to add in my router.

EDIT :
to be more specific
I want all device connected to my wan interface can access to my lan devices.
ex: 192.168.1.200 can ping 192.168.100.55
and 192.168.100.55 can ping 192.168.1.200

Comment: Both networks are directly connected to your router and it has all the routes necessary. You probably need something else but you should be more specific about what do you want to accomplish.

Comment: This isn't a routing issue, it's a firewall issue. As dusan stated in his comment, the router/firewall already has routes from the WAN to the LAN as they are directly connected interfaces. You have to allow the traffic from the WAN to the LAN in the firewall rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct setup would depend on surrounding environment. If "lan" and "wan" are isolated networks (with no connection to internet, which I doubt) you should make sure that

- clients on both networks have router IP address (the one on their side)
  set as their default gateway
- disable NAT on your router (use "classical routing" as they call it in their reference manual)

Comment: isn't possible to use classical routing for one wan and NAT for another?

Comment: Not with this device, as far as I can see in the manual. Anyway, your 'private' devices should not be connected to wan interface at all. You should move them to LAN. But again, any advice requires more details about your setup and network topology.